# Why does this code to render a triangle in SlimDX only show a black screen?

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

Here is the code:

```
 var elements = new VertexElement[] {
                    new VertexElement(0,0,DeclarationType.Float3,DeclarationMethod.Default,
                            DeclarationUsage.Position | DeclarationUsage.Color,0),

                    VertexElement.VertexDeclarationEnd
                };

            VertexDeclaration vd = new VertexDeclaration(m_device, elements);
            m_device.VertexDeclaration = vd;

            var vb = new VertexBuffer(this.m_device, 3 * SizeOf<CustomVertex>(), Usage.Points,
                                                         VertexFormat.PositionRhw | VertexFormat.Diffuse, Pool.Default);

            var ds = vb.Lock(0, 3 * SizeOf<CustomVertex>(), LockFlags.None);
            ds.Write(new CustomVertex(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,0.3f));
            ds.Write(new CustomVertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,0.2f));
            ds.Write(new CustomVertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,0.1f));
            ds.Position = 0;
            vb.Unlock();

            this.m_device.BeginScene();
            this.m_device.SetStreamSource(0, vb, 0, 3 * SizeOf<CustomVertex>());
            this.m_device.DrawPrimitives(SlimDX.Direct3D9.PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 2);
            this.m_device.EndScene();
            this.m_device.Present();
```

The `CustomVertex` struct is defined as below:

```
 internal struct CustomVertex
    {
        public float x, y, z;
        public float color;

        public CustomVertex(float x,float y,float z,float color)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
            this.color = color;
        }
    };
```

The function `SizeOf` defined as below:

```
public static int SizeOf<T>()
{
    return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
}
```

I am trying to display a simple triangle by using code above, without luck, only a black screen pops up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You've got quite a few problems here.

First, the `DeclarationUsage` enumeration maps to [`D3DDECLUSAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172534.aspx) under the hood; these values are not flags, so or'ing them together doesn't make sense. When you create the vertex element array for a vertex declaration, each vertex attribute (position, color, et cetera) must be its own element. Thus, you should initialize `elements` like this:

```
var elements = new [] {
  new VertexElement(0, 0, DeclarationType.Float3, DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.Position, 0),
  new VertexElement(0, 3 * sizeof(float), DeclarationType.Color, DeclarationMethod.Default, DeclarationUsage.Color, 0),
  VertexElement.VertexDeclarationEnd
};
```

Position and color are each given their own vertex element, and (importantly) the color element specifies an offset of `3 * sizeof(float)` since the position element consists of three floats.

Second, you need to make sure your actual vertex data (and thus the vertex structure) matches this declaration. Your current structure has three floats for the X, Y and Z component of position... but only a single float for color. Color is generally a three or four component float (or a 32-bit integer). In the above example, I changed your declaration use `DeclarationType.Color`, which is the 32-bit integer version where each RGBA color component is packed into a particular byte of the integer. Thus, your vertex structure should become:

```
internal struct CustomVertex
{
    public float x, y, z;
    public int color;

    public CustomVertex(float x, float y, float z, int color)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.color = color;
    }
};
```

You will obviously have to change how you fill the vertex buffer (write into the data stream) as well to account for this, or you'll continue to get black screens / garbage because the buffer is misaligned relative to the declaration.

Third, you're also specifying a FVF code to the vertex buffer when you create it; since you're using vertex declarations, you don't need to do that (especially since your FVF code does not match your declaration, either). Instead pass `VertexFormat.None`; you already set the vertex declaration.

Fourth, you specify a usage value of "points" but then try to render a triangle strip. For simplicity, you probably want to put your buffer in the managed pool so you don't have to recreate it when you lose the device. Your buffer creation code can look like this:

```
var vb = new VertexBuffer(m_device, 3 * SizeOf<CustomVertex>(), Usage.None, VertexFormat.None, Pool.Managed);
```

You can also render your scene as a simple triangle list, since you only have one triangle:

```
m_device.DrawPrimitives(SlimDX.Direct3D9.PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 1);
```

Finally, this code looks to all be in a single function. That means you're likely re-creating your resources every frame (bad) or only drawing once (also bad) depending on where the code is located.

I **strongly** suggest that you take a look at the [SlimDX MiniTri sample](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/source/browse/trunk/samples/Direct3D9/MiniTri/Program.cs) for D3D9, which demonstrates a very simple, straightforward way to render a triangle in just about as few lines of code as possible.